# how to tackle the error occurred in ajax update panel reference in MasterPage?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I created a masterpage named "site1" and inserted an updatepanel with a textbox and calendar. when I compile it, it gives error:
The type name 'site1' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel'
this is the following error:

```
Line 179:        }
Line 180:        
Line 181:        [TemplateContainer(typeof(Panel.Site1))]
Line 182:        [TemplateInstanceAttribute(System.Web.UI.TemplateInstance.Single)]
Line 183:        public virtual System.Web.UI.ITemplate Template_head
```

Error occurs on line no. 181

Comment: Please add References: System.Web.Extensions

Comment: Already added.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the name of your project and make sure it has no conflict with the already defined namespace in CLR or ASP.NET.

Comment: that's exactly was the problem, i had solved it by renaming my project. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had named my project as "Panel" which, clashed with the standard control name "Panel". I renamed my project to "ajaxProj" and it worked fine and error free.